# Unable to intall CVS client on Solaris

Tags: bash, solaris, cvs

While trying to install CVS, I got following errors:

```
bash-3.2$ ls

cvs-1.12.13-sol10-x86-local cvs-1.12.13-sol10-x86-local.gz local.cshrc local.login local.profile

bash-3.2$ pfexec /usr/sbin/pkgadd –d /dev2/home/ashish cvs-1.12.13-sol10-x86-local.gz

pkgadd: ERROR: no packages were found in /var/spool/pkg

bash-3.2$ pfexec /usr/sbin/pkgadd –d /dev2/home/ashish/cvs-1.12.13-sol10-x86-local.gz

pkgadd: ERROR: no packages were found in /var/spool/pkg

bash-3.2$ pfexec /usr/sbin/pkgadd –d /dev2/home/ashish

pkgadd: ERROR: no packages were found in /var/spool/pkg
```

Please suggest what could be missing, what else can I do/try?

Comment: Did you try uncompressing the package file?

Answer (score 1):

The pkgadd doesn't process gziped versions to my knowledge. Unpack it, then check if it's really a datastream package with file cvs-1.12.13-sol10-x86-local or pkgchk cvs-1.12.13-sol10-x86-local. Then try /usr/sbin/pkgadd –d cvs-1.12.13-sol10-x86-local

... well and consider updating to Solaris 11 and install developer/versioning/cvs ;)

Comment: And then consider updating from cvs to a version control system that's still being developed...